# Numbering CROSS Apply rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to number the rows created by using cross apply.
Lets say I have a table like this

```
key|value
---+-----
 1 |  A
 2 |  B
```

and I run

```
select * from t CROSS apply String_Split('x,y', ',')
```

Id like to get that result:

```
key|value|value|number
---+-----+-----+--------
 1 |  A  | x   |   1  
 1 |  A  | y   |   2  
 2 |  B  | x   |   1  
 2 |  B  | y   |   2
```

But I have no idead how to achive this; Also the "number" should be resitant to ordering. Any Hints? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `STRING_SPLIT`, if ordinal position is important; it doesn't provide the position and so it cannot be guaranteed. Have a Google for `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`.

Comment: Please, more explain about `number`. What exactly is?

Comment: The number is basicly the order within the the splitted characters/words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another option if 2016+, is to use the JSON KEY.  It would be a small matter to +1 on the KEY if needed

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[value] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A')
,(2,'B')


Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable
 Cross Apply (
                SELECT [Key]
                      ,[value]
                FROM OPENJSON('["'+replace('x,y',',','","')+'"]')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
id  value   Key value
1   A       0   x
1   A       1   y
2   B       0   x
2   B       1   y
```

**EDIT XML / 2014 version**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                      ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace('x,y',',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

Comment: Is there a way for 2014? ;) I basicly faking the string_split with a custom function as I don't have 2016+ support

Comment: @Jaster  No this is 2016+  There is a quick XML version.  Give me a moment

Comment: @Jaster See EDIT

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a CTE. On the CTE I have added the string part number using row_number() over a constant (so it doesn't order by any column and generates the numbers in the original natural order).

```
with string_values as (
  select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as number,
         value
  from string_split('X,Y', ',')
)
select * from t cross join string_values
```

PS: Search for SQL Split String and you will find plenty of functions to replace split_string in SQL Server 2014.